# Add media button does not insert image in the editor

Tags: uploads

I am using twentyfifteen theme. And all plugins are disabled. When I am trying to insert any image in the content of any page , the add media opens the popup, I choose the image, and click on the button, "insert into page". It just close the popup.And nothing happens.

I have check in the browser console. It fires a admin-ajax with the action "send-attachment-to-editor" .And all other parameters are correct for the POST params.

But it response is a html of the site home page.
When in other case, where this features work, I have found that a json response is returned.
I can't even point where is the problem, becuase I used the default twentyfifteen theme and my wordpress version is 4.2.2 . And no plugin is installed.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you upload a new image instead of choosing an existing one from the media library?

Comment: @JamesBarrett Yes, From the editor I click on add image button. Popup opens , upload new image, and click on insert into page, and the same result again. Though the images get uploaded.

Comment: @JamesBarrett And I found another wired behaviour. That when I save settings ->reading  section it redirects me to the site home page. But when when setings->general is saved, it behaves as it should.
Same wired behaviour happens while saving permalinks.
ANd I am usign a custom page as a home page, and fron-page.php  as a template file